# Add Pause to Frame Title

Tags: beamer, footnotes, titles, frame-title, pause

I am using beamer and want to add a `\pause` in the frame title. I wanted to write

```
\begin{frame}{Title\pause\footnote{footnote}}\footnote{footnote...}}
...
\end{frame}
```

This works fine provided the `...` doesn't include any `\pause`s itself (so it seems). However, I do want some `\pause`s in there. In particular, I want there to be a `\pause` immediately after the end of the title. That is, the first screen should be just the main bit of the title, the second have the footnote and then third onwards have the full title + footnote and text from the slide.

Here's a MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title\pause\footnote{footnote}}\pause
1
\pause
2
\pause
3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Beamer's manual:

> The pause command offers an easy, but not very flexible way of creating frames that are uncovered piecewise.
>   [...]
>    much more fine-grained control over what is shown on each slide can be attained using overlay specifications,

That is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title\only<2->{\footnote{footnote}}}
\only<3->{1}
\only<4->{2}
\only<5->{3}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There are much more useful about overlays  that `\only`: `\onslide`, `\visible` `\invisible`, `\uncover`, `\alt`, `\temporal`, etc. Also many environments and `\item`s can also use overlays as `\item<+-| alert@+>`.

Run `texdoc beamer`, is great.

Comment: That looks great, thank you! I Shall check it at work on Monday. Assuming it all works as it looks like it will, I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: That's great, thank you @Fran. I wasn't aware of the `\only` command. It looks extremely helpful :)

Comment: That's very useful, thank you Fran. I have added that information (copy+paste) to your answer. I hope that's ok!

Comment: @SamT ok! Then  I will remove the comment.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this is the following. It's not overly satisfying though -- it's quite possible that it messes up some stuff of which I am not aware. So hopefully someone will have a better one!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\end{frame}

\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}

\begin{frame}{Title\footnote{footnote}} \pause
1
\pause
2
\pause
3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```